# AIDL service from different Projects

Tags: android, eclipse, aidl

I have 2 *** different projects*** within the same workspace in eclipse (most AIDL examples handle different processes within the ***same*** project). Project A is simply HelloWorld, that just displays the sum of 2 numbers. I'm calling this remotely from a client called MyFirstApp to display it.

**Problem:** The onServiceConnected() method is never invoked.

**What I've tried so far:**

**1)** Manifest file has android:process=":remote"> tag. Intent filter is present. AND YES, ALL OF IT IS WITHIN THE application tag. Here it is:

```
<service android:name=".ArithmeticService"
                     android:process=":remote">
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="com.example.helloworld.ArithmeticService"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
    </application>
```

**2)** In my ArithmeticService, the function onBind() does not simply return Null, but returns mBinder. Here it is:

```
@Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // Return the interface
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"IBinder");
            return mBinder;
        }
```

**3)** At client-side, the implementation of the interface is in the same package at the server side.

**4)** In the onCreate() function of my client's MainActivity, I'm calling the function initConnection(), which is as follows:

```
void initConnection(){
    mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mService = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("IRemote", "Binding - Service disconnected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mService = IRemote.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) service);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("IRemote", "Binding is done - Service connected");
            }
        };
        if(mService == null)
        {
            Intent it = new Intent();
            it.setAction("com.example.helloworld.ArithmeticService");
            //binding to remote service
            bindService(it, mServiceConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
}
```

Rest of the code is pretty simple. On click of a button, the remote server should be invoked and the sum of 2 numbrs should be displayed.

Any Help shall be very appreciated.

Comment: The Error I get is, "Unable to start service intent {act=com.example.helloworld.ArithmeticService} U=0 Not found

Answer (score 1):

Got it after days of trying: The name of the project should be in ***small-case***. Is it an Eclipse quirk, or Android quirk ? I don't know. **BUT IT WORKS.**