# How can I call an Android aidl service from other application/project?

Tags: android, aidl, android-service-binding

I want to use my Bind Android service from other applications but all the examples I find are in the same application.

I found some people asking about the same, but they do not share the code or the project structure.

I found some people asking about the same, but they do not share the final code or the project structure.

question 1: [Calling a method in service which is in another app using aidl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892048/calling-a-method-in-service-which-is-in-another-app-using-aidl) (my code looks similar to it)

question 2: [AIDL service from different Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740677/aidl-service-from-different-projects)

As I know I have to put my AIDL fine in the new project, but I am not sure where/the path and how to say that that service is implemented in another app (although I guess that Android figure out this for me as I put in in the manifest of the Service App).

Can anyone helps me with this or have any tips?

Comment: "I am not sure where/the path" -- it would go in the same location as it is in the first project (e.g., `app/src/main/aidl/` in an Android Studio project's `app` module). "how to say that that service is implemented in another app" -- you need to craft an `Intent` that identifies the service from the other app. See [this pair of sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Binding/Remote), covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android).

Comment: @CommonsWare - so if my path is `app/src/main/aidl/com/app1`  I should create the same path in the second application, right? and about the intent, I thought that it was done automatically by the connection class and `bindService`.

Comment: "I should create the same path in the second application, right?" -- yes. Or, if these two apps are modules in the same Android Studio project, you could put the AIDL in a library module and have both app modules depend upon the library. "about the intent, I thought that it was done automatically by the connection class and bindService" -- `bindService()` takes an `Intent`, so you have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate between two different application using AIDL then the package name where you keep your aidl file in both application should be same.

If package name is different for your aidl file of both the application then it will give you error as : **java.lang.SecurityException**

Comment: You may refer to this: http://youtube.com/watch?v=QTxX5X3XxHE